# Pydoc in windows

Tags: python, pydoc

I am learning python from "Learning python the hard way". To use pydoc, I have been asked to type the following in the terminal:

```
python -m pydoc xxx
```

I want to know what the `-m` signifies here. I googled quite a bit but couldn't find any answer.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It basically looks at `sys.path` and load the module (given as argument) and execute its contents as the `__main__` module. Refer to [man page](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) for details.